# Is there an issue with an Event and a Behavior having the same initial value?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

There's something I find unsatisfying with the below code. As I develop `bGameState`, I will add more events. Will the fact that `playerInputE` (and I imagine other `Events`) share the same initial value lead to problems? In other words, is my initial design sound enough to build off of?

Also, is there an alternative to using `changes`? I think I meet the criteria for correct use, but am not sure.

```
makeNetworkDescription :: AddHandler PlayerCommand ->
                           TChan GameState ->
                           IO EventNetwork
makeNetworkDescription addCommandEvent gsChannel = compile $ do
  eInput <- fromAddHandler addCommandEvent
  let playerInputE = accumE initialGS $ updateGS <$> eInput
      bGameState = stepper initialGS playerInputE
      eGameState <- changes bGameState
      reactimate $ (\n -> (atomically $ writeTChan gsChannel n)) <$> eGameState
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand what you are trying to do, but you can use the `accumB` combinator which is defined as

```
accumB x e = stepper x (accumE x e)
```

to remove the definition of `playerInputE`.

It appears to me that the `changes` function is used correctly.